# How can I enter latitude and longitude in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, maps, latitude-longitude

Hi, I'm trying to enter the below longitude and latitude into Google Maps but having a few issues with the format.

Lat. 46 + 23S, Lon. 115 + 22E

I tried entering it into Google Maps but so far, no luck. It was taken from an old diary so I think I may need to change the format somehow.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using Google

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's actually fairly easy, just enter it as a latitude,longitude pair, ie 46.38S,115.36E (which is in the middle of the ocean). You'll want to convert it to decimal though (divide the  minutes portion by 60 and add it to the degrees [I've done that with your example]).

Comment: which is the middle of the ocean

Answer (score 12):

First is latitude, second longitude. Different than many constructors in mapbox.

### Here are examples of formats that work:

- Degrees, minutes, and seconds (DMS): `41°24'12.2"N 2°10'26.5"E`
- Degrees and decimal minutes (DMM): `41 24.2028, 2 10.4418`
- Decimal degrees (DD): `41.40338, 2.17403`

### Tips for formatting your coordinates

- Use the degree symbol instead of “d”.
- Use periods as decimals, not commas.

  - Incorrect: `41,40338, 2,17403`.
  - Correct: `41.40338, 2.17403`.
- List your latitude coordinates before longitude coordinates.
- Check that the first number in your latitude coordinate is between `-90` and `90` and the first number in your longitude coordinate is between `-180` and `180`.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to convert to decimal; you can also enter 46 23S, 115 22E. You can add seconds after the minutes, also separated by a space.

Answer (score 2):

for higher precision. this format:

45 11.735N,004 34.281E

and this

45 23.623, 5 38.77